# How do I click Next button First step check Validation and second step Not check Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I make custom Wizard with validate but when I click Next button to First step check validation and when click next step click on next button it's not check validate and skip the step.

HTML is as given below:

```
<form>
            <div class="form-main">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                    <p id="error"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                    <p id="error"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <p id="error"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <p id="error"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-btn">
                    <button type="button" id="prev" onClick="prevBtn(this);">prev</button>
                    <button type="button" id="next" onClick="nextBtn(this);">next</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </form>
```

Script Below:
separated function used update status means find index and update ,validation,next button and previous button.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('.form-main > .form-input:nth-child(1)').addClass('open');
    $('.form-main > .form-input:not(".open")').addClass('close').hide();    
});

var $div = $('.form-input');
var submits = $('#submit').css('display','none');
index = 0;

function updateStatus(a){
    $div.eq(index).removeClass('current').addClass('close').hide();
    index += a;

    $div.eq(index).addClass('current').removeClass('close').show();

    $('#next').toggle((index !==$div.length-1));
    $('#prev').toggle(index !== 0); 

    if(index == ($div.length - 1)){
        submits.toggle(index !== 0);
    }else{
        submits.hide();
        }
}

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

function validation(){
    var inputValue = $(input).val();
    var inputType = $(input).attr('type');  
        if(inputValue !== ''){
            updateStatus(+1);
        }else{      
            error.innerHTML = "please enter the value";
        }
}

function nextBtn(){
    validation();
}

function prevBtn(){
    updateStatus(-1);
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that you aren't using this function?
Did you notice that creating a function to use a function doesn't make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have made few changes and got it to work.

Changed

```
var inputValue = $(input).val();
```

to below, as you need to check for current visible element

```
var inputValue = $('input:visible').val();
```

Secondly, you cannot have `error` as same ID for multiple elements, so I have removed that. IDs are unique.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.form-main > .form-input:nth-child(1)').addClass('open');
  $('.form-main > .form-input:not(".open")').addClass('close').hide();
});

var $div = $('.form-input');
var submits = $('#submit').css('display', 'none');
index = 0;

function updateStatus(a) {
  $div.eq(index).removeClass('current').addClass('close').hide();
  index += a;

  $div.eq(index).addClass('current').removeClass('close').show();

  $('#next').toggle((index !== $div.length - 1));
  $('#prev').toggle(index !== 0);

  if (index == ($div.length - 1)) {
    submits.toggle(index !== 0);
  } else {
    submits.hide();
  }
}

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

function validation() {
  var inputValue = $('input:visible').val();
  var inputType = $(input).attr('type');
  if (inputValue !== '') {
    updateStatus(+1);
  } else {
    $('input:visible').next().html("please enter the value");
  }
}

function nextBtn() {
  validation();
}

function prevBtn() {
  updateStatus(-1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-main">
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-btn">
      <button type="button" id="prev" onClick="prevBtn(this);">prev</button>
      <button type="button" id="next" onClick="nextBtn(this);">next</button>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)